# Tomcat Worker Threads

Tags: tomcat, jersey-2.0

What is the role of tomcat worker threads when using @ManagedAsync executors? Assuming that all of the services that I am going to build will leverage @ManagedAsync.

Moreover, how can I increase the number of workers thread pool when I am using @ManagedAsync

Comment: I think the answer is "there is no role of Tomcat worker threads when using `@ManagedAsync` executors" but I'm not entirely sure. My guess is that Jersey manages all of that with its own thread pool. I say "I think" and "my guess" because I know a lot about Tomcat ant nothing about Jersey. Since Tomcat doesn't know about `@ManagedAsync`, I assume it's just a Jersey thing. Since Tomcat generally doesn't allow web applications to allocate request-processing threads from its thread pools, my conclusion is that Jersey must be handling this itself.

Comment: If that is the case, I can set the tomcat worker threads to 0 when using ManagedAsync? I am trying to figure what is the exact role of Tomcat worker threads in case if I am using @ManagedAsync the reason being under load these numbers needs to be tuned.

Comment: I suspect that if you set the Tomcat worker threads to zero, the server will remain inert. Remember that requests have to arrive at the server somehow. Tomcat handles the initial connection and hands it off to Jersey along with the resources required to handle the request (e.g. request, response, and, of course, the thread running the code). If Jersey wants to delegate that work to yet another thread and all the request-processing thread to return to Tomcat's pool, that's fine. But Tomcat's pool cannot be empty if you expect Tomcat to handle incoming connections.

Comment: The Jersey thread will surely have to communicate back to the client indirectly by using Tomcat's threads to move the data back and forth. When handling an asynchronous request (and response), your code (or Jersey's) must fire messages to Tomcat telling it that data is ready for transport. Tomcat uses its own threads to shuttle the data back to the client.

Comment: Back to your original question: "tuning". Do you have any problems, yet, or are you under the impression that "tuning" is a thing you have to do before you have any data about how your service will be used, or the expected load-profile? Beware of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).